# Take Everything To Left Of Last "." In String

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that has multiple "." in it.  I am trying to capture everything to the **LEFT** of the last "."  I tried this syntax (as it will always be 6 characters I want to capture)

```
var result = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('.') - 6);
```

but this is returning the 6 characters that I want as well as the extension.  A sample of what the file name will look like  is

```
The.Red.The.Blue.The.Green.Notification.Paper.R23B22.docx
```

in my snippet the code returns `R23B22.docx` I am only wanting to return `R23B22`

How would I alter this code to return my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `String.Split()`:

```
var splits = filename.Split('.');
var result = splits.Length > 1 ? splits[splits.Length - 2] : "";
```

Comment: That does it!  Is it personal preference to use `String.Split()`over `Substring()` or is that just the "better" thing to do with C#?

Comment: it just seemed natural to me @MitchMahoney

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
/([^.]+)\.[^.]+$/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ukyrkc/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify how many characters you want:

```
var result = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('.') - 6, 6);
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/a2JF5z

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var filename = "The.Red.The.Blue.The.Green.Notification.Paper.R23B22.docx";
var result = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('.')-6);

int index = result.IndexOf(".",StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
if (index > 0)
{
   result = result.Substring(0, index); // result = R23B22
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one:

Remove the last chunk, then split by `.` and take the last piece.

```
string output = filename.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf(".")).Split('.').LastOrDefault();
```

or

```
string output = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename).Split('.').LastOrDefault();
```